# Draggable and resizable div with containment goes out of containment

Tags: jquery

i'm busy with a timetable script, for that i need to use jQuery draggable and resizeable.
but is you can see in te jsFiddle the draggable has a parent, but you can drag it 10px over the parent, every click moment.
EDIT:
the thing i need is that it can not be dragged outside the container.
who can help

http://jsfiddle.net/QBX2B/1/

html:

```
        <div class="containment" style="display:block; height:40px; width:150px; background-color:#f2f2f2;">
        <div class="baldie" style="display:block; height:40px; width:150px; background-color: rgba(214, 255, 210, .7);"/>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
                $('.baldie').resizable({
                        containment: "parent",

                    }).draggable({
                        grid: [5,0],
                        containment:"parent",
                        drag: function( event, ui ) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: What you want exactly pls define properly ??

Comment: you want `baldie` div to be dragged outside the parent div ?

Comment: no it may not get outside bladie but right now it can on chrome

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `position:relative;` to the container solves the issue.

I have modified Your code check run and you can check it :-

```
<div class="containment" style="position: relative; display:block; height:40px; width:150px; background-color:#f2f2f2;">
            <div class="baldie" style="display:block; height:40px; width:150px; background-color: rgba(214, 255, 210, .7);"/>
        </div>
```

Check it :-

[Jquery UI resizable issue expands beyond containment (draggable also used)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980833/jquery-ui-resizable-issue-expands-beyond-containment-draggable-also-used)

Comment: @Learner Even using the jsfiddle from the link you posted, im still able to drag the dragabble outside the containment

Comment: There is a ticket for this bug suggesting your workaround or modify jquery ui plugin (weird solution): http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4489

Answer (score 0):

Inline styling is not good practice. It results in messy and sometimes hard to read code. Using CSS to modify the margin and padding of the parent we can allow the child to cover the entire parent.
[JSFiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/QBX2B/5/)

```
.baldie{
  display:block; 
    height:40px; 
    width:150px; 
    background-color: rgba(214, 255, 210, .7); 
    margin:1px;
}
.containment{
    position:relative;
    display:block; 
    height:40px; 
    width:150px; 
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

Comment: Like @user2389793, i still can drag element outside containment by few pixels each time using chrome win7

Comment: you need to click and drag to the right side if you do this multiple times it goes 10px to the right every click

Comment: @n8ross in your exampe i can still drag the dreagable dive outside the parent div by draging the dragable div to the right side of the parent, than i click it multiple times and in the mean time i drag it to right and the div goes outside the border

Comment: @n8ross im using chrome but if you take my exaple in chrome and you click the green hold it and drag it to the right and release it, you should have the same thing as i have... if not i don't know what is wrong but i can drag it outside the div, than it is a complete mystery

Comment: @user2389793 [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/QBX2B/3/) I was finally able to reproduce your error. Adding a 1px margin and padding seems to do the trick

Comment: I removed my previous comments since they were not relevant to the solution. I also edited the original answer to reflect the last fiddle i updated: [http://jsfiddle.net/QBX2B/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/QBX2B/3/)

Comment: @user2389793 after some more testing I realized the padding isn't necessary only the margin. [Final Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QBX2B/5/)